# Using gcc compile from c to python pyd get "undefined reference to" message

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw

I am trying to compile c-code to python pyd and had a "undefined reference to" error message. I found similar problems that have been asked before at stackoverflow and it might be caused by missing function or library.

```
D:\mspy>python setup.py
build --compiler=mingw32
running build
running build_ext
building 'calculations' extension
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall 
-IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy 
-IC:\Python27/include 
-IC:\Python27\include 
-IC:\Python27\PC -c calculations.c -o 
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\calculations.o
In file included from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804,
from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
from calculations.c:6:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:12: warning: ignoring #pragma message
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\calculations.def
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\calculations.o
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\calculations.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 -lm -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\calculations.pyd
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\calculations.o:calculations.c:(.text+0xf3f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\calculations.o:calculations.c:(.text+0x3ba6): more undefined references to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple' follow collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

The C code will look something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "Python.h"
#include "arrayobject.h"

...more defined functions
```

The setup.py file reads:

```
import sys
import numpy
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

# make include paths
numpyInclude = numpy.get_include() + '/numpy'
pythonInclude = sys.prefix + '/include'

# make setup
setup(
    name = 'calculations',
    version = '1.1',
    author = "Martin Strohalm",
    maintainer = 'Martin Strohalm',
    description = "Fast calculations for mspy.",
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('calculations', ['calculations.c'],
            include_dirs=[numpyInclude, pythonInclude],
            libraries=['m']
        )
    ],
)
```